# Modification in PostRegister Action Method - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using inbuilt Authentication System in laravel 5.1. I am trying to modify the PostRegister Action Method.

We can find the code in below mentioned path.

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
```

Can you suggest where should I do the modicications if I have to add one more field in User Table. I have already updated the migration file and database is updated also.

Comment: http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/09/25/adding-custom-fields-to-a-laravel-5-registration-form/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open this file `\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php`

Change you two methods like following:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'new_field_name' => 'required|any_other_validation_if_needed',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'db_column_name' => $data['new_field_name'], // it will more bug free if you use same db_column_name and new_field_name
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```